# Do check out in a document with jquery

Tags: document-library, jquery, check-out

I'm using SharePoint 2013.
I need do check out in a library document using JQuery.

Someone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use REST and the [CheckOut method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841%28v=office.15%29.aspx#bk_FileCheckOut).

Altered from MSDN for jQuery and non-app approach:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('<your file>')/checkout",
  headers: {
     'X-RequestDigest': $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
  }
});
```

Comment: I will try this.

Comment: Forgot about X-RequestDigest, see update

Comment: How I get the URL of my file? Because I dont know the folder where he are.

Comment: What do you have to begin with? Such as item ID, Document library name/id etc

Comment: Library name, id of document and the URL.

Comment: By URL do you mean File URL? Because that is what you need. In any case there are other ways to reach the file, for example `/_api/Web/Lists('<list guid>')/Items(<item id>)/File/Checkout`

Comment: URL of edit form.

Comment: eirikb: Could you please expound on your answer. I have implemented your code, no error is produced, but the file is not checked out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JohnColtrane The example code above will not print any errors. Check your network log (e.g., Chrome dev tools and Network-tab, then check the response body). Or add `.error(function(){console.log(arguments)})`